# How do I make list group item active without anchor tags?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to style a [basic list-group](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-basic) item `active` to highlight it (change background color etc). Bootstrap supports the `active` class just through [Linked items](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#list-group-linked).

I have something like:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

to make `Cras justo odio` style as active
what is the best practice to do that?

Comment: I can't understand this. What is your intended result? What have you tried? Place a fiddle link your your question.

Comment: what i understand do you want to replace `active` with `highlight` right ? https://jsfiddle.net/fs6vdzL0/1/

Answer (score -1):

You need to locate all of the list items and remove the `active` class from them. Then you need to set the `active` class on the clicked item. You can do something like this...

https://jsfiddle.net/gtzqw471/2/

Comment: Solutions should be presented in the answer, not just on another website.

Answer (score -3):

There is straight solution for you. The better option should be use `a` with default cursor

```css
.my-list {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<nav id="my-list" class="list-group">
  <a class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</nav>
```

**demo** http://www.bootply.com/117174

Comment: You don't necessarily stick to `<ul>` tags - you can use `<div>` tags instead, with the same class like `<div class="list-group">...</div>`.

Comment: You're suggesting invalid HTML - aside from the fact that OP explicitly asked for a solution without using links.